# Similar objects - different contents (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am newbie. Trying to make an app where ViewController will have a lot of similar objects vertically but with different contents in it (heading, image and button).

How to implement this correctly? I assume that the block/object which I want to have the same properties (height, length, button alignment...) all the time , should be declared as a class, and after it should be initialized with different objects (images, buttons, headings). Am I right?

[image]

Comment: The question is not really clear. You want add fixed 3 vertical content or flexible (1, 2,3, 4, 5 ....). Though in any case, I suggest create 1 object subclass object UIViewController with name VerticalViewController. Then, you can add VerticalViewController as many as you like. It reduces many affort. If you want me show example code, please vote up and comment here. Tks a lot :).

Comment: These objects will be the additional themes for the app (free, paid & share to get free). There will be a predefined number of themes about 20-25. + the ViewController will be scrollable. So this "VerticalViewController" should have all the settings for the placement of: Heading-title, button, image-button and auto resizing for different iPhones? Yes, please show me the example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm so sorry, you misunderstood me, I originaly show xample code about VerticalViewController, as your comment, I think your want me show all project, it costs a lot of affort. OK, Instead of doing that I will show your necessary steps to research to complete this task. 1. Custom Table View 2. Auto Layout (basic OK).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you will want to use a `UITableView` and subclass `UITableViewCell` that defines all the common subviews.

Comment: UITableView will have all those UITableViewCells? In UITableView will be defiend the spacing btwn the objects and its adaptiveness for different screen sizes? And in UITableViewCell will be all the properties for the "Objects". After I declare UITableViewCell i should only init it with different buttons, images, headings?

Answer (score 1):

```
class VerticalViewController: UIViewController {
    var headerTitle: String
    var buttonTitle: String
    var headerImage: UIImage

    init(headerTitle: String, buttonTitle: String, headerImage: UIImage) {
        self.headerTitle = headerTitle
        self.buttonTitle = buttonTitle
        self.headerImage = headerImage
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I'm so sorry, you misunderstood me, I originaly show xample code about VerticalViewController, as your comment, I think your want me show all project, it costs a lot of affort. OK, Instead of doing that I will show your necessary steps to research to complete this task. 1. Custom Table View 2. Auto Layout (basic OK).